# Credential error while accessing data via nodejs through couchdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, couchdb

I am trying to make a front end using node js and angular. 
For the backend, I am trying to access the couchdb data in the code as follows:

```html
const express = require('express');  
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');  
const path = require('path');  
const NodeCouchdb = require('node-couchdb');  
  
const couch = new NodeCouchdb({  
auth:{  
user: 'admin'  
password: '**'  ///hidden for security
}  
});  
couch.listDatabases().then(function(dbs){  
console.log(dbs);  
});  
  
const app = express();  
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));  
app.use (bodyParser.json());  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));  
app.get('/', function(req,res){  
 res.render('index');  
});  
app.listen(3000, function(){  
 console.log('Server is started on Port 3000');  
})
```

My couchdb host is something like this
*http://admin@***@172.26.132.189:5984*

The above code is just trying to list the databases in my couch db server. But when I run the code it gives me the following error:
**{error:unauthorised: name or password is incorrect}**

I tried defining my host also in the above code by adding these lines:

```html
const couchExternal = new NodeCouchDb({
    host: 'couchdb.external.service',
    protocol: 'https://172.26.132.189',
    port: 5984
});
```

But still gives me the same error.

I am giving the correct credentials.
Can someone please help me with a solution or tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `:/5984` ... are you sure that `/` should be there? usually the port is declared using `:5984`

Comment: also, `const couch = NodeCouchdb({` shouldn't that be `const couch = new NodeCouchdb({`?

Comment: thirdly, protocol should be `https` not `https://172.26.132.189` because https is a protocol, but `https://172.26.132.189` isn't

Comment: @JaromandaX There were some Typos in the questions so I have edited them..sorry for that

Comment: @JaromandaX I have tried everything giving protocol as https and host as the URL but still the error didn’t  get resolved

Comment: when everything else is excluded, the only possible issue is that you are supplying the wrong username or password, as the error suggests

Comment: @JaromandaX No I'm absolutely sure I'm giving the right credentials

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a coma after the user i.e. it should have been like: user:'admin', password.... so on since auth is an object variable. Check out this video for more help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6LUMXrAoCE&list=PLx3witYKF_5KjQj8i_OTrYbm8WNcZdccG

Comment: I agree with your answer. But when you link a video it would be nice to add a time stamp to the point you're referring too. 35 min video seems a bit long for such a simple fix.